# How to repeat a value in numpy choice probabilities

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to repeat 0.1 five times as the total number of probabilities required equals to 9. Any suggestions? In R, it can be done by using `rep` function. Any similar function in python?

```py
import numpy as np
np.random.choice(np.arange(1, 4, 1/3), 3, p=[[0.1]*5, 0, 0.3, 0.2, 0])
#> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
#> 
#> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
#> 
#> Traceback (most recent call last):
#>   File "F:\miniconda_pf\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\reprexlite\code.py", line 69, in evaluate
#>     result = eval(str(self).strip(), scope, scope)
#>   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
#>   File "mtrand.pyx", line 918, in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.choice
#> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: Concatenate it. `p=[0.1]*5 + [0, 0.3, 0.2, 0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may simply expand your `[0.1]*5` list like:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.choice(np.arange(1, 4, 1/3), 3, p=[*[0.1]*5, 0, 0.3, 0.2, 0])
```

`*` used for the purpose. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2921847/15981043)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
probs = [0.1 for _ in range(5)]
probs.extend([0, 0.3, 0.2, 0])
np.random.choice(np.arange(1, 4, 1/3), 3, p=probs)
```